# How to send and receive data when using Indy10?

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus

I am create a proxy client using SOCKS5, in [rfc1928](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt), I should send a connect message to server, and server back to me a message:

```
           client send to server:

           +----+----------+----------+
           |VER | NMETHODS | METHODS  |
           +----+----------+----------+
           | 1  |    1     | 1 to 255 |
           +----+----------+----------+

           and then server should return message following:

           +----+--------+
           |VER | METHOD |
           +----+--------+
           | 1  |   1    |
           +----+--------+
```

my code below:

```
procedure TForm1.ConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  RecvBuff: TBytes;
  fSize: Int64;
begin
  with TcpClient do
  begin
    Connect;
    // send \x01\x01\x05 to SOCKS5 server
    IOHandler.WriteLn('#01#01#05');
    fSize := IOHandler.ReadInt64;

    IOHandler.ReadBytes(RecvBuff, fSize);
    // Check server response is \x01\x01
    if (TBytes[0] = byte('#01')) and (TBytes[1] = byte('#01')) then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Server responsed!');
    end;

  end;
end;
```

I am new to pascal, i cannot compile this code in Lazarus, there is no Indy TCP operation runnable demo i can found, and I do not know bytes operation in pascal, please help me figure out above code problem.

Comment: On what line is the error message?  And is sending a string #01#01#05' really what you want to send?

Comment: First, using `WriteLn` and `ReadInt64` is the COMPLETELY wrong thing to do for the SOCKS protocol. Second, Indy has built in support for connecting a `TIdTCPClient` through a SOCKS proxy, using the `TIdSocksInfo` component. Configure `TIdSocksInfo` as needed for SOCKS (v4 vs v5, username/password, etc), then attach it to your `TIdTCPClient`'s IOHandler before calling `Connect()`. That is all you need

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks for your reply, I wanna to implement a SOCKS5 client instead connect a TCP server through a SOCKS5 proxy

Comment: @TangMonk that doesn't really make sense, but whatever. Your code is still completely wrong for the SOCKS protocol. The first 3 bytes are NOT `01 01 05`, you misread the documentation, the part you quoted is telling you byte *sizes*, not byte *values*. I suggest you re-read the RFC more carefully, and study `TIdSocksInfo`'s source code in `IdSocks.pas` to see how Indy implements the SOCKS protocol.